# Bad Bot blocking Revisited

Tags: robots.txt, botattack

I've read a lot about bad bot blocking, php scripts, .htaccess techniques, etc...

Is this a valid method?

Since .htacces can rewrite and send a bad bot a 403 deny or forward to something like spam poison, is it possible to Disallow a folder, then through .htaccess in that specific folder redirect to spampoison? Since Apache reads each .htaccess independently and follows specific instructions, then a bad bot not following robots.txt would just be redirected. Or anyone trying to access, /badbot/ or whatever I choose to call my trap folder.

Comment: You're basically describing a form of [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29). The bot trap John references in the answer he linked to below is one particular implementation, but this is a more general term for the technique.

Answer (score 2):

I've [recommended similar tactics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/how-do-spambots-work/3799#3799) before.

Answer (score 2):

What you suggest (use a bot trap to trap the bad bod, and then block it using .htaccess or your favourite scripting language) is indeed a much-used technique for dealing with robots from the dark side.

You may want to look at another thread here about this particular technique: [Tactics for dealing with misbehaving robots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/tactics-for-dealing-with-misbehaving-robots/39828#39828)

If you're looking for sample code that tells you how to implement it, just Google for "bot trap".  Here is just one such page: http://www.kloth.net/internet/bottrap.php that I found very instructive.

Answer (score 1):

If the bots aren't changing IP's often why let them hit your server and take up usage? I would ban the IPs's first in hosts.deny / ipchains then use .htaccess and robots.txt as back up